# Pandas select the year end quarters in a DF

Tags: python, pandas

I resampled a DF to produce a DF that is summed by quarter, (Semi pleased that I got that far :-)) now I just want the last quarter of each year (on which I'll be calculating the % change from the prior year).
df looks like (but through 2012..); so I want a DF with all and only the 12-31 dates?

```
            Units
date    
2000-06-30   6120
2000-09-30   7346
2000-12-31   5925
2001-03-31   7542
2001-06-30   9916
2001-09-30   9547
2001-12-31   8063
```

Comment: do you want aggregate or filter data?

Comment: filter the data so I have each December and only the Decembers (they are already aggregated quarterly data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your index is a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [0]: df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

Now you can extract all sorts of information from the index and use it to subset your original dataframe:

```
In [1]: df.ix[df.index.quarter == 4]
Out[1]:
            Units
2000-12-31   5925
2001-12-31   8063
```

To calculate the quarter over quarter change:

```
In [2]: curr = df.ix[df.index.quarter == 4]
In [3]: prev = df.ix[df.index.quarter == 4].shift()
In [4]: curr/prev
Out[4]:
               Units
2000-12-31       NaN
2001-12-31  1.360844
```

Comment: Beautiful.. I thought something like ix index quarter existed just could not apply it!....